# Blender doesnt render my fire and smoke

Tags: rendering, fire

I wanted to make a VFX in Eeve where an fire is in my kitchen, but the fire and Smoke simulation doesnt work. In the solid mode everything seems ok [image] but in the render view there is only smoke [image].When I hit F12, there is the domain full of smoke and the outflow object [image]. But no fire and really smoke... Please help me ! You can write the answer in german or english! But please do it